# Trouble with the trigger to field update

Tags: trigger

Trigger should look at the Case record to determine if the "xyz__c" checkbox is true/false

**-If True, go to #2**

**-If False, Trigger does nothing**

Trigger should evaluate the Case record's associated Account record to determine if the "xyz__c" checkbox is true/false

**-If True, Trigger does nothing**

**-If False, Trigger updates the field to True**

BOTH OBJECT ACCOUNT AND CASE HAVE SAME FIELD XYZ__c

I have implemented this trigger but i am not sure this will work or not.

```
Map<Boolean, Boolean> MapCaseToGetNextRecordList = new Map<Boolean, Boolean>();

for(Case c : trigger.New){
    if(MapCaseToGetNextRecordList.containsKey(c.xyz__c) != true){
        break;
    }
}

for(Account acc : [select Id, xyz__c from Account]){
    if(acc.xyz__c != True){
        acc.xyz__c = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the accounts you need to update with a simple query, then update the field and commit the changes back to the database.

```
Account[] accounts = [select id from account where id in (select accountid from case where xyz__c = true and id in :trigger.new) and xyz__c = false];
for(account record: accounts) {
    record.xyz__c = true;
}
update accounts;
```